# Pronunciation of 'smoothed'

Tags: pronunciation

The *-ed* suffix for the past form of verbs is pronounced

- /-d/ after a voiced sound (e.g.: *allowed*: /əˈlaʊd/),
- /-t/ after a voiceless one and (e.g.: *walked*: /wɔːkt/)
- and /-ɪd/ after /t/ and /d/ (e.g.: *halted*: /hɔːltɪd/).

How is *-ed* suffix pronounced in the past of verbs ending in /ð/ and /θ/?

How do you pronounce *smoothed* in the sentence 'He **smoothed** his hair back.':

- /smu:ðd/
- or /smu:ðɪd/?

By the rules above, I guess that the correct answer should be the first form, that incidentally, as a non-native speaker, I find a bit difficult to utter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The rules are correct: /smu:ðd/. And unlike some of the horrible consonant clusters at the ends of words in English (e.g. *sixths*), native English speakers don't generally simply this one, so you should just keep on trying to pronounce it.

Answer (score 0):

As Peter Shor notes in the comments, the correct pronunciation is /smu:ðd/. If you are having trouble with that pronunciation, native speakers will probably consider /smu:ðt/ as sounding more correct than /smu:ðɪd/.

Comment: Or /smuːθt/, which I am fairly sure occurs quite frequently in native speech.